# Is there an easier way to tell HTTPBuilder to ignore an invalid cert?

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

Per the [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/ssl.html), you can go through a rather clunky process of export a cert from a browser manually and getting it recognized locally. Is there anything similar to curl's `--insecure` switch to make this practical?

Comment: You can install your own trust manager and hostname verifier to skip the SSL certificate checks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242335/how-to-use-ssl-with-a-self-signed-certificate-in-groovy

Comment: It is reported here -> http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMOD-266 but no response yet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Good news everyone! :-)
Just found out that new version (0.7.1) of HttpBuilder introduces method:

```
ignoreSSLIssues()
```

This solves all problems regarding invalid SSL certificates (of course you have to be aware that it also decreases security).

More information about this method: https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/SSL (section at the bottom)

Comment: Couldn't be better :)

Answer (score 5):

Found a way that non involve import of certificates or httpbuilder hacks

```
//== HTTPBUILDER IMPORTS
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
//== END HTTPBUILDER IMPORTS

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import java.security.SecureRandom
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry

def http = new HTTPBuilder( "https://your_unsecure_certificate_host" )

    //=== SSL UNSECURE CERTIFICATE ===
   def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")              
   sslContext.init(null, [ new X509TrustManager() {public X509Certificate[]   
   getAcceptedIssuers() {null }
   public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
   public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
   } ] as TrustManager[], new SecureRandom())
   def sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
   def httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", sf, 443)
   http.client.connectionManager.schemeRegistry.register( httpsScheme )
   //================================

//do your http call with the http object
http.request( ....
```

Comment: `new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)` didn't work for me, constructor not found. I had to do this: `def sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext)
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)`

Comment: If you get a java.lang.VerifyError exception try to move the code from your controller or service to a groovy or java class. I think grails artificats enhancer conflicts with some of the above code.

Comment: Hey Fabiano, the solution you gave doesn't compile in GroovyConsole Version 2.1.3 (i.e. a recent version).  Would you please let me know what is wrong/provide a fix?  Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ray. The sample is missing HttpBuilder imports.