# Groovy can't compile the code from a solution given on StackOverflow

Tags: grails, groovy

Answer 1 to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638005/is-there-an-easier-way-to-tell-httpbuilder-to-ignore-an-invalid-cert) provides some Groovy code, but it doesn't compile (for me, Groovy Console Version 2.1.3, or in my Grails 2.2.3 app).

Can you please assist in letting me know what I need to change to make this code work?  The error I get is:

```
 unexpected token: public at line 14, column: 52  (... which is the "public X509 Certificate[]")
```

For quick reference the code solution provided in Answer 1 is:

```
 import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
 import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
 import java.security.SecureRandom
 import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
 import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme
 import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry

 def http = new HTTPBuilder( "https://your_unsecure_certificate_host" )

 //=== SSL UNSECURE CERTIFICATE ===
 def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")              
 sslContext.init(null, [ new X509TrustManager() {public X509Certificate[]   
 getAcceptedIssuers() {null }
 public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
 public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
 } ] as TrustManager[], new SecureRandom())
 def sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
 def httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", sf, 443)
 http.client.connectionManager.schemeRegistry.register( httpsScheme )
 //================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a newline between the `public X509Certificate[]` and `getAcceptedIssuers() {null}` as a result of pasting the code in.

Try removing the newline (and formatting the code to something moderately readable while you're at it) and the error should disappear.

Comment: Thanks. The various anonymous classes are definitely a bit confusing to me perhaps also because of the arrays.  You are right removing the newline fixes it, but this too seems unobvious to me -- i.e. can't one have as much whitespace/newlines as desired?

Comment: There are certain places where whitespace is important. This is one of many reasons why coding standards are important.

Comment: The issue here is that the second line is a valid expression by itself. Groovy automatically assumes `Object` as the return type since it is not specified. Since the second line is a valid expression, the compiler doesn't know to combine it with the previous (or potentially next) line. It gets ambiguous very quickly.

Comment: I see, the assumed return type threw me off. Unfortunately I have a new issue now :-(, Groovy Runtime Exception: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext, org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier).   Any thoughts on this? Running it in Grails 2.2.3.

Comment: The first comment on the SO post you copied this from handles this exact issue.

Comment: Thanks man.  I used it.  Have no idea why the constructor doesn't wor (posted it in another question).  I still think I'm not getting some basic Groovy stuff ...