# How to use Groovy to access simple web service?

Tags: web-services, groovy

I'm definitely a noob regarding web services. I'm trying to use groovy as a client to access a simple web service. The web service has basic authentication and uses https.  In the browser, I'd use some thing like this:

```
https://myserver.com/app/services/soap/call?script=MyService&username=me&password=secret
```

How would I call this from groovy?  I tried to figure out how to use groovy-wslite, but I couldn't figure it out (I know how to get to service with a URL...no idea what all this body and header...etc...is or how it related to the url I know works).  I also tried using a real simple http sort of call:

```
'https://myserver.com/app/services/soap/call?script=MyService&username=me&password=secret'.toURL().text
```

But that didn't work.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized right after posting that the problem was likely related to SSL and a self-signed cert.  I found this post:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/reading-https-url-self-signed

that uses this library:

https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

The solution then became very easy:

```
def req = 'https://myserver.com/app/services/soap/call?script=MyService&username=me&password=secret'
req = HttpRequest.get(req)
req.trustAllCerts()
req.trustAllHosts()
println(req.body())
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but this works for me. :D

Comment: Here's another way to work with self-signed certificates using the built in HTTP support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242335/how-to-use-ssl-with-a-self-signed-certificate-in-groovy

Comment: Thanks.  The library is working great, but always good to have a second option.