# Enable Java/Groovy URL connection to ignore SSL Cert Errors w/o Setting setDefaultSSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, groovy, jenkins, https

There are several examples out there [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022717/java-and-https-url-connection-without-downloading-certificate)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242335/how-to-use-ssl-with-a-self-signed-certificate-in-groovy) of how to configure HTTPS in Java/Groovy to ignore SSL certificate errors.  In short they all create a custom TrustManager, add it to an SSLContext and then install the resulting SocketFactory as the default connection factory for HTTPS connections.  And of course they comes with all the requisite warnings about MITM attacks and how dangerous this is.

Indeed in my situation where I am writing a groovy script to be run inside of a Jenkins job, setting the default socket factory is nuts.  It would have affects well beyond that of my script.  So my question is, how do you accomplish this for a specific connection or specific HTTP client and not for all connections/clients?  In other words, how to I localize such a change to just my transient piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class BasicHttpClientFactory implements HttpClientFactory {

    private String proxyHost;
    private Integer proxyPort;
    private boolean isSocksProxy = false;
    HttpClient httpClient;
    final Integer maxConnections = new Integer(10);
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(BasicHttpClientFactory.class);

    @Override
    public HttpClient createNewClient() {

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = null;
        try {
            SSLContextBuilder builder = SSLContexts.custom();

            builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            SSLContext sslContext = builder.build();

            sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    sslContext, new X509HostnameVerifier() {
                        @Override
                        public void verify(String host, SSLSocket ssl)
                                throws IOException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void verify(String host, X509Certificate cert)
                                throws SSLException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void verify(String host, String[] cns,
                                String[] subjectAlts) throws SSLException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }


        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .register("https", sslsf)
                .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
    poolingConnManager.setMaxTotal(maxConnections);
    poolingConnManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnections);

    ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
        @Override
        public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
            return 60 * 1000;
        }
    };

    if (proxyHost != null) {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setProxy(proxy).setConnectionManager(poolingConnManager).setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy).build();
    }else {
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setConnectionManager(poolingConnManager).setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy).build();
    }
    return httpClient;
    }

    public void setProxyHost(String proxyHost) {
    this.proxyHost = proxyHost;
    }

    public void setProxyPort(Integer proxyPort) {
    this.proxyPort = proxyPort;
    }

    public void setSocksProxy(boolean isSocksProxy) {
    this.isSocksProxy = isSocksProxy;
    }
}
```

And interface :

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

public interface HttpClientFactory {

    public HttpClient createNewClient();
}
```

After that You could use :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new BasicHttpClientFactory().createNewClient();
```

If You need any ideas how to merge it into Your project, just post some info - maybe i'll come up with some ideas ;)