# Bypass SSL verification in gradle

Tags: http, gradle, ssl, build.gradle

please help me with skipping SSL verification while launching build.gradle file. For some reasons currently I can`t use SSL certificates, so I need to skip SSL verification to reach repository(internal Nexus repository) and download libraries. Everythin is done in Gitlab CI pipeline.

Here is mistake that stops build.gradle:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:           sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
```

I have tried some earlier mentioned decisions, like:

1. Creating gradle.properites file with adding next values:

```
    systemProp.http.ssl.insecure=true
    systemProp.http.ssl.allowall=true
    systemProp.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

2. Using answer to this question [How to use SSL with a self-signed certificate in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242335/how-to-use-ssl-with-a-self-signed-certificate-in-groovy) via using https://github.com/arteme/gradle-trust-all